# How to setup haproxy to connect to backend server using HTTP/3 QUIC?

Tags: haproxy, http3, quic

I am able to configure HAProxy to to present itself as an HTTP/3 server by following instruction here: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/announcing-haproxy-2-6/

```
bind :443 ssl crt server.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
http-response set-header alt-svc "h3=\":443\";ma=900;"
```

But what do I need to put in haproxy.cfg to to indicate to HAProxy that the backend server supports HTTP/3 and it should use QUIC protocol to connect to it? I tried the same `quic4@` prefix but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
server s1 quic4@192.168.4.4:443
```

Comment: There is nothing about this in haproxy documentation. You probably want to ask this question on https://discourse.haproxy.org/ or on their mailing list https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need this line also to enable quic protocol ;

```
# enables HTTP/3 over QUIC
bind quic4@:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/foo.com/cert.pem alpn h3
```

Comment: This is for the frontend. The question is about the backend.

Comment: Also,  Haproxy needs to be compiled with QUIC flag.  The one I installed doesn't come with QUIC enabled.